# cfcontent doesn't refresh after ajax call

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I'm streaming my pictures through a cfcontent call, and am trying to have the pictures refreshed after allowing users to rotate them 90 degrees. In my main photo page, I have a featured picture div, a gallery div, and a photo details div. On page load, the featured/gallery divs are unpopulated unless there are session variables present, in which case the relevant templates are included. If the divs are unpopulated, clicking the nav bar menu triggers ajax calls to load in the selected pictures.

All this is working well. My problem is when there is a picture selected and loaded, and when a user wants to rotate it. The rotate button triggers a call to rotate and save the picture (which works), and then tries to refresh the featured/gallery divs to show the updated picture. Here's where it breaks. Although the picture is rotated, and refreshing the entire page shows it in its updated form, the ajax calls don't show the updated picture. These refresh calls have been used successfully when attached to other event handlers, so I don't think they're being called incorrectly. Is there something mysterious about using cfcontent perhaps?

here's my attempt at isolating the relevant bits:

Main page:

```
<div id="featured_pic">
  <cfif isDefined('session.currentPhotoName') and #session.currentPhotoName# neq "">
    <cfinclude template="featuredImage.cfm">
  </cfif>
</div>

<div id="gallery_container">
  <cfif isDefined('session.category') and isDefined('session.param') 
    and #session.category# neq "" and #session.param# neq ""
  > 
    <cfinclude template="photoGallery.cfm">
  </cfif>
</div>
```

Featured image.cfm:

```
<cfif isDefined('url.file_name')>
  <cfset session.currentPhotoName = #url.file_name#>
</cfif>

<cfoutput>
  <cfset thisImage = #session.currentPhotoName#>    
  <img 
    id="photoPlaceholder"
    src="/#application.root_name#/administration/PhotoManagement/displayPhoto.cfm?thisImage=#thisImage#" 
    width="600px" 
  />
</cfoutput>
```

DisplayPhoto.cfm:

```
<cfcontent 
  type = "image/*" 
  file = "C:\#replace(application.local_file_path, '/', '')#\Photos\#thisImage#" 
  deleteFile = "No"
>
```

And the js to make it happen (wrapped in $(document).ready()):

```
$('#rotate').live('click', function(){
    var id = $('#docID').val();
    var title = $('#title').text();
    title = $.trim(title);

    // rotate the image and refresh the details container   
    $('#details_container').load('Administration/PhotoManagement/photoDetails.cfm', {'DOC_ID': id, 'title': title, 'rotateFlag': true}, function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
            $("#details_container").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });

    // refresh the gallery
    var category = $('#currentCategory').val();
    var param = $('#currentParam').val();
    $.get(
        'Administration/PhotoManagement/photoGallery.cfm', 
        {category:category, param:param},
        function(response, status, xhr){
            if (status == "error") {
                var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                $("#photos").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
            } else {
                $('#gallery_container').html(response);
            }
        }
    );

    // refresh the featured image
    $('#featured_pic').load('Administration/PhotoManagement/featuredImage.cfm',
        {'file_name': title});

});
```

Note that as a newbie to ajax, I've been experimenting with .load(), .get(), and .ajax() to see what works. From jQuery In Action, I gather that I should be using GET for these actions, true?

EDIT: following up on suggestions below, I tried calling it as:

```
$.ajax({url:'Administration/PhotoManagement/featuredImage.cfm',
        cache: false,
        data: {file_name: title},
        success: function(response){
            $('#featured_pic').html(response);
            alert('success');
        }
    });
```

and I've also tried setting

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false});
```

inside my $(document).ready(), to no avail. The picture rotates, if I refresh the entire page I can see the change, but the ajax call, although it tells me I have succeeded, doesn't show the updated picture.

Answer (score 6):

Ajax requests using the Get method are cached.  Either append a dummy time parameter or use a Post request.

Comment: Ah... I see. So add ?_=[time_stamp], or just use $.ajax(cache:false) instead?

Comment: user724075, just add something like {url:'Administration/PhotoManagement/featuredImage.cfm?cachebreaker=' + new Date()

Comment: As pointed out in the edited question, I've tried setting cache:false to no avail.

Comment: The cache option was a more "recent" addition to jQuery, so I am not sure what version you are using.  Also you may want to try Dan Short's code there just to be sure.  I neither of those work, you can try using a ajax POST.  If that doesn't work then AJAX cacheing is not the issue.

Comment: Looking at the console in firebug, I see that jQuery is appending &_=1313067003643 to the query string, so I can safely assume that cache:false is working. So I agree, I don't think ajax caching is the issue here. Googling for issues with <cfcontent> caching doesn't turn up anything either.